# Sum up numbers after string "number"

Tags: full-text-search, text-processing

I have a text file with words and positive numbers, separated by some whitespace, e.g.

```
A dog has a ball number 49     number    34 number    A
Cats number   58
...
```

I want to sum up all the numbers that occur after the string "number". If after a string "number" is not a number, then it doesn't matter.

For example, in this case the answer would be 49+34+58, which is `141`.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu, and I really don't know how to approach this rather than brute-forcing by myself. But I have a very large file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) s = s+$i }; END { print s+0 }' test.txt
```

Awk reads the file, line per line. For every line, the blocks marked by `{}` are executed. blocks can be guarded by a condition: a regular expression, ..., and `BEGIN` and `END`, which are 'true' for the first line, and the last line, respectively.

This means that awk exeutes the first block for every line (because it is unguarded).

Furthermore, awk does not really have a type system -- all strings. But you can use arithmetic on the strings - in which case they are magically converted to numbers. If you do arithmetic on strings, which are not numbers, they evaluate to '0'. 
This means: "asdf" + 1 = 1; 2+4 = 6; "asdf" + 0 = 0;

Variables don't have to be declared - and default to the empty string, which has the numerical value of '0'.

The next awesomeness of awk is that it automatically splits the current input line into fields. The field separator can be specified, but defaults to whitespaces. The single fields can be accessed by `$1`, `$2`, ... `$NF`, i.e. `NF` is the number of fields. `$0` is the contents of the full input line.

And there you have it: you look over all 'fields' of the current line. The numerical values of all fields (which are 0 for strings) are accumulated in the variable `s`. After reading everything (`END`), the sum is printed.

EDIT: this might conveniently work, but does not really answer the question, because it does not consider 'number' - sorry.

A fix:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) if ($i == "number") {s = s+$(++i)} }; END { print s+0 }' test.txt
```

that way, it also results in 141 for input like:

10 A dog has a ball number 49     number    34 number    A
  Cats 1000 number   58

Comment: If it's not too much trouble, could you please explain briefly what your code does?

Answer (score 2):

You could separate the input with awk by setting `number` as the record separator:

```
awk -v RS=number '{ sum += $1 } END { print sum }' infile
```

Here's a grep, coreutils and bc alternative:

```
(<infile grep -Eoi 'number[[:blank:]]+[0-9]+' \
| tr -s '[:blank:]' | cut -d' ' -f2 | head -c -1 \
| tr '\n' '+'; echo
) | bc
```

Output:

```
141
```

Comment: there is one caveat: RS uses only the first character, so RS=number is the same as RS=nothing; http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_19.html

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer: This is true for the old awks, e.g. original awk and nawk, but not for more recent versions, e.g. mawk and gawk, which treat RS as a regular expression if it is longer than one char.

Comment: right! but my testcase failed with: 'nonumber 123', which is also counted, as RS separates the 'nonumber' into 'no' 'number'. (GNU Awk 3.1.8)

Comment: That's true any string containing `number` will be considered a separator. If it should only count when it is alone it should be anchored at word boundaries, e.g. `-v RS='\\<number\\>'`.